# Difference of two (possibly dependent) variables is Gaussian iff the variables are Gaussian?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

In probability, a reknown result is that the sum (or the difference) between to Gaussian random variables is in turn normally distributed. What about the converse? If the difference of two (**possibly dependent**) random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$  is normally distributed, must $X_1$ and $X_2$ be Gaussian random variables? The answer is positive in the case where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_decomposition_theorem

But what if they're dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is normally distributed and $Y$ is any random variable then the difference $(X+Y)-Y$ is normal. So the answer is NO.

Comment: Sure, eventually the answer was trivial. I was thinking to the problem more from a statistical perspective than from a probabilistic one, so I was missing the obvious possibility you've pointed out.